# How can I make parent categories bold in a product table with Woocommerce?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, css, woocommerce

I am using a table products to filter categories. What I need is to make only the parent categories bold. In this search result (e.g. `https://demo.motorocker.gr/?swoof=1&antalaktika=scooter`) we need to bold only parent categories.

[image]

I tried to make it through CSS but it didn't work. I tried `li#select2-wcpt_filter_product_cat-zx-result-ac7d-elastika` but I see that every time each category comes out with a separate ID.

Any advice?

Comment: Please see [ask] and take the [tour]. You're expected to show some code here.

Comment: As Zach suggests below, you should use nested lists instead of using text and whitespace characters as formatting. Your document should make sense if read without any styling.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend adding them as sub items instead of hard coding a dash in the beginning. Once you do that you can target them this way:

```
ul#select2-wcpt_filter_product_cat-jl-results > li{font-weight:bold;}
```